# Prove that, if nullity$(A^k)=$ nullity$(A^{k+1})$ for some $k$, then nullity$(A^k)=$ nullity$(A^{k+j})$ for all $j\geq1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

I'm attempting to solve this via induction.

The base case, $j=1$, is given by assumption. Then, we let our hypothesis be that nullity$(A^k)=$ nullity$(A^{k+s})$ for $j=s$, and show that nullity$(A^k)=$ nullity$(A^{k+s+1})$ for $j=s+1$. Thus, let $x$ be an element of the null space of $A^{k+s}$. That is, $A^{k+s}x=0$. Then $(A^{k+s+1})x=(AA^{k+s})x=A(A^{k+s}x)=A(0)=0$, so $x$ is an element of the null space of $A^{k+s+1}$. Thus NS$(A^{k+s})\subseteq$ NS$(A^{k+s+1})$, implying that nullity$(A^{k+s})\leq$ nullity$(A^{k+s+1})$. So by the inductive hypothesis, we have that nullity$(A^k)\leq$ nullity$(A^{k+s+1})$.

I'm struggling to see how to get this to be a strict equality. I tried the element argument in the reverse direction in attempts to get the subspace inclusion in both directions, but this didn't get me anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\ker T_2 \subset \ker T_1T_2$, so $\text{nullity}(T_2)\leq \text{nullity}(T_1T_2)$.
In particular, $\text{nullity}(T^k)\leq\text{nullity}(T^{k+1})$.

Assume that $k$ is such that $\text{nullity}(A^k)=\text{nullity}(A^{k+1})$.
Suppose there were $j\geq 1$ with $\text{nullity}(A^k)\neq \text{nullity}(A^{k+j})$, and assume WLOG that $j$ is the smallest integer with this property.
We would necessarily thus have $\text{nullity}(A^k)<\text{nullity}(A^{k+j})$ and $j\geq 2$.
Let $v\in \ker(A^{k+j})\setminus\ker(A^k)$.

---

> **Claim:** $A^iv\neq 0$ for all $i<k+j$.

*Proof of the claim:* Suppose there were some $0<i<k+j$ with $A^iv=0$, and assume WLOG that $i$ is the smallest integer with this property.
We must have $i>k$, for otherwise this would contradict $v\not\in \ker A^k$.
Then $0<i-k<j$, so that

$$A^{k+(i-k)}v=A^iv=0.$$

This implies $\text{nullity}(A^{k})\neq\text{nullity}(A^{k+(i-k)})$, which would contradict the minimality of $j$. $\square$

---

By design, $A^{j-1}v\in \ker A^{k+1}$.
But $\ker A^{k+1}=\ker A^k$, because their nullities are the same and $\ker A^k\subset\ker A^{k+1}$.
This would imply that $A^{k+j-1}v=0$, which would contradict the claim. $\square$

---

EDIT: Okay, let's try a proof by induction.
We want to show that for all $j\geq 1$, $\text{nullity}(A^k)=$ $\text{nullity}(A^{k+j})$.
This is equivalent to showing that $\ker(A^k)=\ker(A^{k+j})$ for all $j\geq 1$.

The base case is actually given, so it suffices to show the inductive step.
Suppose that for some $j\geq 1$ we have that $\ker(A^{k+j})=\ker(A^k)$.
We will show that $\ker(A^{k+j+1})=$ $\ker(A^k)$.
In light of the very first observation of this post, we actually need only show that $\ker(A^{k+j+1})\subset \ker(A^k)$.

Indeed, let $v\in \ker(A^{k+j+1})$.
Then $A^{k+j+1}v=A^{k+j}Av=0$.
It follows that $Av\in \ker(A^{k+j})$.
By our inductive hypothesis, $\ker(A^{k+j})=\ker(A^{k})$, hence $Av\in\ker(A^{k})$, that is, $A^{k+1}v=0$.

But this means $v\in \ker(A^{k+1})$, which by the problem's hypothesis equals $\ker (A^k)$.
In other words, $v \in \ker(A^k)$, so $\ker(A^{k+j+1})\subset\ker(A^{k})$, as we set out to prove.

Comment: I'm a little confused on why $i$ must be greater than $k$. Certainly if they're equal, we contradict the fact that $v$ is not in the null space of $A^k$, but why is it necessarily the case that if $i$ is less than $k$ then $v$ would be in the null space of $A^k$?

Comment: Actually I think I can answer that myself... the nullspace of $A^s$ is a subspace of the nullspace of $A^t$ for all $s<t$, so if $v$ is an element of the nullspace of $A^s$, then $v$ is an element of the nullspace of $A^t$.

Comment: Why is $A^{j-1}v$ in the null space of $A^{k+1}$?

Comment: Because $A^{k+1}A^{j-1}v=A^{k+j}v$, and since $v\in\ker(A^{k+j})$, $A^{k+1}A^{j-1}v=0$.

Comment: Got it. This solution makes sense, but I'm going to leave it unsolved for the moment. The context this was asked in assumes a "simple" solution. I'm hoping that putting a bounty on this will bring an inductive proof. If not, I'll accept this one.

Comment: Would you prefer a proof by induction?

Comment: Although I would note that induction is equivalent to well-ordering (the existence of a least element), which we used for $j$ $($and $i$ in the proof of the claim$)$.

Comment: Well, the reason I'm thinking induction is because the question was phrased with a hint to use induction. This is part of preparatory materials for a graduate entrance exam, and of the ~50 questions I have solved, the solution you have here is by far the most dense. Which makes me think there's a more elegant solution. Though I do see your point about the actual logic being the same for an inductive argument.

Comment: See the edit on the answer. I think you will find it suits conventional induction arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The condition $\text{nullity}(A^k)=\text{nullity}(A^{k+1})$ is the same as the condition $$A^{k+1}x=0\implies A^kx=0. \tag {1}$$ Prove this yourself.

Now we are to prove $\ker(A^{k+2})=\ker(A^{k+1})$ ($\ker A$ means nullspace of $A$), which would imply $\text{nullity}(A^{k+2})=\text{nullity}(A^{k+1})$. Observe $$A^{k+2}x=0\implies A^{k+1}(Ax)=0\implies A^k(Ax)=0\implies A^{k+1}x=0,$$ where the second implication follows from condition $(1)$. Hence $\ker(A^{k+2})\subseteq\ker(A^{k+1})$. That $\ker(A^{k+1})\subseteq\ker(A^{k+2})$ is obvious.

Conclude the desired result by induction.